# Change the size of the nodes (tkz-tab)

Tags: tikz-pgf

The size of the nodes is not modified for the images of the function (second row of the table)

How to modify the thickness of the lines ?

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{fontenc,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{babel}


\tikzset{arrow style/.append style = {shorten > = 1pt,
                               shorten < = 1pt,
                               > = stealth}}

\tikzset{from style/.append style ={-,dashed}}

\tikzset{t style/.append style ={dashed}}

\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.2,0} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}]
  \tkzTabInit[lgt=1.5,espcl=1.5,deltacl=0.7,color, colorC = fondpaille,colorV=fondpaille]{$x$ / 1 , $B(x)$ / 3}{$0$, $8$,$18$}%
  \tkzTabVar{-/ $-117$, + / $75$, - / $-225$}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replacing your `tikzpicture` specification with a shorter one `\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]` could solve your problem. I also recommend to avoid the `scale` option for more consistent fonts in your final document.

Comment: you declare `thick` lines ... try to remove `thick` from the `tikzpicture` options. or do i misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Zarko In fact, we can change the style of the arrows, for example `tikzset{arrow style/.append style = {shorten > = 1pt,
                               shorten < = 1pt,
                               > = stealth}}`, and I wanted to know if we could do the same thing for the thickness of the lines.

Comment: @Fabrice, of course:. for example:`\tikzset{arrow style/.append style = {line width=..., shorten > = 1pt, shorten < = 1pt, > = stealth}}` or instead of `line width=...` use predefined thickness  names  (from `ultra thick` to `ultra thin`). or i did misunderstand what you mean with lines?

Comment: @Zarko I was talking about the option `\ tkzTabInit [lw = 2pt] `to change the line thickness of the table.